# Helm (openshift): no available release name found

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm

Output of `helm version`:

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Output of `oc version`:

```
$ oc version
oc v1.5.1+7b451fc
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://192.168.99.100:8443
openshift v3.9.0+71543b2-33
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
```

Cloud Provider/Platform (AKS, GKE, Minikube etc.): Openshift

I'm getting this error message on tiller when I'm trying to install this package:

Client:

```
$ helm install incubator/vault --set vault.dev=false
Error: no available release name found
```

Server:

```
[tiller] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 preparing install for 
[storage] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 getting release "awesome-tarsier.v1"
[storage/driver] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 get: failed to get "awesome-tarsier.v1": configmaps "awesome-tarsier.v1" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in the namespace "kube-system": User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in project "kube-system"
[tiller] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 info: generated name awesome-tarsier is taken. Searching again.
[storage] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 getting release "limping-tarsier.v1"
[storage/driver] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 get: failed to get "limping-tarsier.v1": configmaps "limping-tarsier.v1" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in the namespace "kube-system": User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in project "kube-system"
[tiller] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 info: generated name limping-tarsier is taken. Searching again.
[storage] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 getting release "coy-lemur.v1"
[storage/driver] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 get: failed to get "coy-lemur.v1": configmaps "coy-lemur.v1" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in the namespace "kube-system": User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in project "kube-system"
[tiller] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 info: generated name coy-lemur is taken. Searching again.
[storage] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 getting release "dapper-kudu.v1"
[storage/driver] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 get: failed to get "dapper-kudu.v1": configmaps "dapper-kudu.v1" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in the namespace "kube-system": User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in project "kube-system"
[tiller] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 info: generated name dapper-kudu is taken. Searching again.
[storage] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 getting release "kneeling-opossum.v1"
[storage/driver] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 get: failed to get "kneeling-opossum.v1": configmaps "kneeling-opossum.v1" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in the namespace "kube-system": User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get configmaps in project "kube-system"
[tiller] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 info: generated name kneeling-opossum is taken. Searching again.
[tiller] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 warning: No available release names found after 5 tries
[tiller] 2018/08/01 07:36:22 failed install prepare step: no available release name found
```

I've installed `minishift` and I've logged in using admin user.

**EDIT**

I've also added incubator repository:

```
➜  ~ helm repo list
NAME            URL                                                      
stable          https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com         
local           http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts                             
incubator       http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts-incubator
```

and I've checked vault is available:

```
➜  ~ helm search vault
NAME                            CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION                                       
incubator/kubernetes-vault      0.2.1           0.5.2           The Kubernetes-Vault project allows pods to aut...
incubator/vault                 0.12.0          0.10.1          A Helm chart for Vault, a tool for managing sec...
incubator/vaultingkube          0.1.2           0.1.1           vaultingkube takes config maps and secrets stor...
stable/vault-operator           0.1.0           0.1.9           CoreOS vault-operator Helm chart for Kubernetes   
incubator/goldfish              0.2.6           0.9.0           A Helm chart for Goldfish - Vault UI
```

I've also tried with:

```
➜  ~ helm install incubator/vault --set vault.dev=false --set rbac.create=true
```

But I'm getting the same message:

> Error: no available release name found

Answer (score 0):

That's probably due to privelege escalation issues.

My first thought would be enabling rbac in when deploying the chart. 
By the way you haven't mentioned if you added already the incubator repo. Just in case you didn't:

```
$ helm repo add incubator http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts-incubator
```

Back to the point where you need to enable rbac when deploying the chart:

```
$ helm install incubator/vault --set vault.dev=false --set rbac.create=true
```

I find this [article](https://rancher.com/understanding-kubernetes-rbac/) very helpful explaining the k8s RBAC.

Answer (score 0):

First you may add incubator from vault.

`helm repo add incubator http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts-incubator`

And now you can install vault.

`helm install incubator/vault --set vault.dev=false`

Finish